# Oracle create function fails

Tags: oracle, function, syntax, user-defined

can somebody tell me why the below function should fail compilation?

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION CONCAT_LIST
      (cur IN SYS_REFCURSOR, sep IN VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN  VARCHAR2
IS 
  ret VARCHAR2(32000); 
  tmp VARCHAR2(4000); 
BEGIN 
    --open cur;
    loop 
      fetch cur into tmp; 
      exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
      if ret is null then
       ret := tmp; 
      else 
        ret := ret || sep || tmp; 
      end if;
    end loop; 
    RETURN ret;
  END;
```

The error message I get is

```
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:
 <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> SELF_
 LONG_ double ref char time timestamp interval date binary
 national character nchar
```

Comment: That SQL works fine on my 10gR2 environment - what Oracle version are you on?

Comment: I'd suspect some dodgy character that looks like a space but isn't.

Comment: The error message should give you a line number.  What is it?  It's a vital clue.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies guys. I copied the script from here and recompiled a few minutes ago, it compiled just fine. So Gary Myers could be right, the issue perhaps is due to some character looking like a space character.